# WCF endpoint not found

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm following a tutorial in a book to implement push notifications for Windows Phone. This is the markup of the service:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service.PushService" CodeBehind="PushService.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

As you see, a factory is added, although I don't really understand what it's for. When running the service, I get a `"endpoint not found"` error. When I remove the factory from the markup, the error disappears, but I get an empty page.

Any idea what could cause this error or how to fix it? If you need more code, please tell me.

Thanks

EDIT:
My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your .config file

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx

Comment: I've added the .config file, thanks..

Comment: WebServiceHostFactory is for REST endpoints (WebHttpBinding). In your configuration you have not specified any endpoints explicitly. Which means the default endpoints feature of the service host that you have mentioned will kick in. So in your case WebServiceHostFactory will try to add default REST end point. The reason why it runs on deleting the factory attribute is - once you delete the factory attribute the default service host is being used which adds baicHttpBinding endpoints.

Comment: @Bv202 how are you *testing* your web service? Where does the `endpoint not found` error appear - browsing to it as a web? When running the service? etc.

Comment: It appears when browing to it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the endpoint configuration in your web.config.

Add this to your web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Service.PushService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding"
                contract="Service.IPushService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: basicHttpsBinding or WebHttpBinding?

Comment: should be the same as on this line <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />

Comment: after you fill the address, if you get an AddressAccessDeniedException, then open Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For those who absently implement the method in Service.svc that its definition is absent in IService causes the same exception.

This is forgotten

```
[OperationContract]
 string CheckHMAC(string hMac);
```

But implemented

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/CheckHMAC/{hMac}")]
public string CheckHMAC(string hMac)
{//}
```