# WCF Service exception: was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: json, wcf, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ajax call in _Layout.cshtml.

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ttsFunction() {
        serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/wscccService.svc/RunTts";
        var data = new Object();
        data.text = $('#speak').val();
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceUrl,
            data: jsonString,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                console.log("xhr: " + xhr.readyState);
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    console.log('page not found');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Basically I wanted to click a button that is in another View to invoke this service.
The button in Community.csthml is:

```
<button id="btnSpeak" onclick="ttsFunction();">Speak</button>
```

When I typed the svc path in the browser, I found an exception in Tracelog folder under IISEXPRESS.

The exception is:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &amp;#39;/wscccService.svc/&amp;#39; was not found or  does not implement IController.
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController&amp; controller, IControllerFactory&amp; factory)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
 --&gt;</Data>
```

The service itself is simple:

```
namespace service
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface Iwservice
   {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "RunTts")]
    string RunTts(string text);
   }
 }
```

To save space, I won't post web.config unless you need it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/wscccService.svc` file seems to reside in an ASP.NET MVC application directory. MVC's routing will intercept the request and start looking for a controller named `wscccService.svc`, which it can't find.

Just [add an ignore route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362925/ignore-folder-in-asp-net-mvc) to your route configuration.

Comment: I don't have a physic wscccService.svc file, I used fileless skills.<serviceActivations>
       <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
        relativeAddress="wscccService.svc"
        service="service.wservice"/>
  </serviceActivations>

Comment: I don't know the purpose of your comment, is it to disprove my answer? The existence of a file or directory does not matter for the routing of URLs. Try it.

Comment: No, how to add it? I have  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); in RouteConfig

Comment: I think it'll just be `routes.IgnoreRoute("wscccService.svc")`, or perhaps `routes.IgnoreRoute("{allServices}.svc/{*pathInfo}")`. See the [documentation](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx).

Comment: I added it, but 'Endpoint not found' when I typed the service url in the browser.

Comment: Please, show some research effort. The issue you mention is an entirely different error that has already been answered on this site before. Searching the web for "WCF endpoint not found" gives tens of thousands of search hits, usually when the name of the service doesn't match the name in the `web.config`. :-)

Comment: Okay, I will do it and I am going to mark your answer since the exception is gone.:)

Comment: Thanks. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130879/wcf-endpoint-not-found) for your other issue.