# WCF service "endpoint not found", what's the cause?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, endpoint, svc

I wrote WCF service and the following is the web.config file. 
When I punch in url:

http://localhost:50705/EmpInfoService.svc/GetEmpSalary/B1234

It gives me an error:

> ### Service
>
> endpoint not found

I found two places that are suspicious....

- from previous questions
  [WCF endpoint not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130879/wcf-endpoint-not-found)

where it is asking for missing end point configuration. I do have the endpoint configuration:

```
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="servicebehaviors" 
               name="EmployeeService.EmpInfoService">
        <endpoint address="" contract="EmployeeService.IEmpInfoService" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

- Second, for some reason, I cannot set

  `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"` to "true"

like illustrated in the [Youtube Tutorial for WCF service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMO6aIXRp1U)

- The following is my web.config file. Can you please take a look and potentially give me some suggestions? Thank you!

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servicebehaviors">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="servicebehaviors" name="EmployeeService.EmpInfoService">
        <endpoint address="" contract="EmployeeService.IEmpInfoService" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I believe you created a WCF service hosted in IIS. So you don't need to specify an end point in the configuration file. Try and replace the entire service model section with the following and see where it goes

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```